# how to get key having special character(_) in object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, object

I would like to know how to fetch the keys in object contains only underscore in javascript.

I would like to get the output with text before underscore, as shown

```
var obj={
  cn_start: "SG",
  cn_end:"TH", 
  cn1_start:"ML",
  cn1_end:"IN"
}
```

Expected Output

```
[
  cn, cn1
]
```

Comment: would there be a key with multiple underscore, ex: cn_start_time?

Comment: @GlenK thanks for reply, no , will be in format `cn_start`

Answer (score 0):

I believe using reduce is better, but for better readability, I use for loop. 
First, you get the keys using Object.keys, then iterate the keys finding the ones with '_' and push the prefix if it does not exists yet.

```
var obj={
  cn_start: "SG",
  cn_end:"TH", 
  cn1_start:"ML",
  cn1_end:"IN"
}

const keys = Object.keys(obj);
let underscoreKeys = [];
keys.forEach(key => {
  if(key.substring('_')){
    const prefix = key.split('_')[0];
    if(underscoreKeys.indexOf(prefix) < 0){
      underscoreKeys.push(prefix);
    }
  }
});

console.log(underscoreKeys);
```

Answer (score 0):

For an Internet Explorer compatible answer, try the following:

```
var obj={
  cn_start: "SG",
  cn_end:"TH", 
  cn1_start:"ML",
  cn1_end:"IN"
}

var objkeys = Object.keys(obj);

var underscorekeys = [];

for(var i = 0; i < objkeys.length; i++) {
    var index = objkeys[i].indexOf("_");
    if(index > -1) {
        var prefix = objkeys[i].substr(0, index);
        if(underscorekeys.indexOf(prefix) < 0)
            underscorekeys.push(prefix);
    }
}

console.log(underscorekeys);
```

The other answers use 'arrow functions' or 'lambda functions' which is ES6 and **[not IE compatible](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the keys from your object using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), then filter out all the keys which don't have an underscore in them. Next, you can [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each key to a substring of itself by removing the underscore `_` and its trailing text (using `.replace(/_.+/, '')`). You can then use a [`new Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to remove any duplicates, and [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to turn that set back into an array:

```js
const obj={
  cn_start: "SG",
  cn_end:"TH", 
  cn1_start:"ML",
  cn1_end:"IN"
}

const get_keys = obj =>
  Array.from(new Set(Object.keys(obj).filter(k => k.includes('_')).map(k => k.replace(/_.+/, ''))));
  
console.log(get_keys(obj));
```

If you know all your keys will have an underscore in them, then you can remove the `.filter()`.

Answer (score 0):

Split the key names by '_' and add them to `Set` to get unique keys.

```js
var obj = {
  cn_start: "SG",
  cn_end: "TH",
  cn1_start: "ML",
  cn1_end: "IN"
};

const keys = [...new Set(Object.keys(obj).map(key => key.split("_")[0]))];

console.log(keys);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const keysNames = Object.keys(myObj);//returns the array ['keyName','keyName'];
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.